# Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ an $R$-module, and $A, B ≤ M$ two submodules of $M$ such that $M = A ⊕ B$. Prove that $M/A \cong B$.

Tags: modules, direct-sum

> Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ an $R$-module, and $A, B ≤ M$ two submodules of $M$ such that $M = A ⊕ B$. Prove that $M/A \cong B$.

Comment: Where are you stuck at?

Comment: am I right using second isomorphism theorem? M/A = A⊕B/A= A+B/A= B/A intersection B = B

Comment: That's fully correct: $M=A\oplus B$ means $M=A+B$ and $A\cap B=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying that $M=A\oplus B$, means

1. $M=A+B$, and
2. $A\cap B=\{0\}$.

Thus the second isomorphism theorem yields
$$
M/A=(A+B)/A\cong B/(A\cap B)=B/\{0\}\cong B
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I initially forgot second isomorphism theorem, so stupid.