# $M_1$, $M_2$ are submodules of a module $M$, then $M = M_1 + M_2$ and $M_1 \cap M_2 = 0$ implies M is isomorphic to $M_1 \oplus M_2$?

Tags: modules, direct-sum

I saw the two properties mentioned by the post on

> [Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ an $R$-module, and $A, B ≤ M$ two submodules of $M$ such that $M = A ⊕ B$. Prove that $M/A \cong B$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978407/let-r-be-a-ring-m-an-r-module-and-a-b-%E2%89%A4-m-two-submodules-of-m-such)

With intuition I think if $M_1$, $M_2$ are submodules of a module $M$, then $M = M_1 + M_2$ and $M_1 \cap M_2 = 0$ implies M is isomorphic to $M_1 \oplus M_2$, but I did not find this in books I could find. Is this true?

Comment: 1) Have you tried proving it? 2) Have you tried to mimic the proof for vector spaces and see if it works in this case?

Comment: You probably didn't find this specific property in the books because most books prove (or leave as an exercise) a much more general property to which this is a special case. The mentioned property is true. To prove it yourself, I suggest you start with building the most natural homomorphism $\phi: M_1\oplus M_2\to M_1+M_2$ you can think of...

Comment: I see. Just being not confident. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also, @Hamed could you tell me some books providing the more general property? Thanks!

Comment: If you look at any commutative algebra book and look for "split exact sequence", that's a (first order) generalization of this statement. See for example Atiyah and MacDonald (but again, any other book also has this).

Comment: @Hamed Thanks for help!